# mysql- table comparison error

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, CAR_1 and CAR_2. Table CAR_1 contains more columns and more records than CAR_2.

Running the query below returns 4647 records:

```
(SELECT CAR_1.ID FROM CAR_1, CAR_2 WHERE 
CAR_1.ID = CAR_2.ID AND 
CAR_1.MODEL = CAR_2.MODEL AND
CAR_1.SYMBOL = CAR_2.SYMBOL AND
CAR_1.MAKE = CAR_2.MAKE AND
CAR_1.ORIGIN = CAR_2.ORIGIN) AS table_all
```

While running the same query without the last 2 columns comparison returns 4600 records.

```
(SELECT CAR_1.ID FROM CAR_1, CAR_2 WHERE 
CAR_1.ID = CAR_2.ID AND 
CAR_1.MODEL = CAR_2.MODEL AND
CAR_1.SYMBOL = CAR_2.SYMBOL ) AS table_min
```

I would like to to get the 47 records whose make and origin are different, so i tried the sql below but it does not seem to be working properly

```
select * from (SELECT CAR_1.ID FROM CAR_1, CAR_2 WHERE 
CAR_1.ID = CAR_2.ID AND 
CAR_1.MODEL = CAR_2.MODEL AND
CAR_1.SYMBOL = CAR_2.SYMBOL AND
CAR_1.MAKE = CAR_2.MAKE AND
CAR_1.ORIGIN = CAR_2.ORIGIN) AS table_all
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
(SELECT CAR_1.ID FROM CAR_1, CAR_2 WHERE 
CAR_1.ID = CAR_2.ID AND 
CAR_1.MODEL = CAR_2.MODEL AND
CAR_1.SYMBOL = CAR_2.SYMBOL ) AS table_min
WHERE table_all.ID = table_min.ID 
)
```

I would appreciate it if someone can show me the error

Comment: is there a chance that make and origin are `NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it as simple as:

```
SELECT 
  CAR_1.ID 
FROM 
  CAR_1, CAR_2 
WHERE 
  CAR_1.ID = CAR_2.ID AND 
  CAR_1.MODEL = CAR_2.MODEL AND
  CAR_1.SYMBOL = CAR_2.SYMBOL AND 
  (CAR_1.MAKE <> CAR_2.MAKE OR CAR_1.ORIGIN <> CAR_2.ORIGIN);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CAR_1.ID FROM CAR_1
outer join CAR_2 On 
CAR_1.ID = CAR_2.ID 
AND  CAR_1.MODEL = CAR_2.MODEL 
AND CAR_1.SYMBOL = CAR_2.SYMBOL 
AND CAR_1.MAKE = CAR_2.MAKE 
AND CAR_1.ORIGIN = CAR_2.ORIGIN
Where Car2.id is null
```

Will give you the id's of all cars in car1 with no matching record in Car2

More efficient than exists, or not in subqueries.